# how to create regex for drive file url?

Tags: javascript

i want to add regex for drive file url for this format **https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID**

```
        var googleid = '';
        var regexp = /https:\/\/drive\.google\.com\/file\/d\/(.*?)\/(edit|view)\?usp=drivesdk/;
        var match = sharingurl.match(regexp);
        if ( match ){
            googleid = match[1];
        }
        else{
            regexp = /https:\/\/drive\.google\.com\/open\?id\=(.*?)$/;
            match = sharingurl.match(regexp);
            if ( match ){
                googleid = match[1];
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What exactly is the problem and what are you trying to match? Your regex attempts here have a lot more information than the URL shown, since you're trying to match stuff like `edit|view` that aren't mentioned otherwise. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: As ggorlen stated above, it's unclear what the breadth of you requirement is, but answering it literally it would be `https:\/\/drive\.google\.com\/uc\?export=download&id=(.*)` https://regex101.com/r/OsDZq5/1

Comment: ggorlen above regex are correct i want to add one more expression for the url format

Comment: diamonddrake thanks for the solution it works.